# Split a string a string using special formatting in c++

Tags: c++, string, split, quotes

I'm trying to split a string like this :

"aaaaaaaa"\1\"bbbbbbbbb"

with the quotes included, in order to obtain aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb.

I found different methods to get the split of the string but the presence of quotes and slash causes many problems.

For example if i use string.find i can't use string.find("\1\");

does anyone know how to help me ? thank you

Comment: You need to escape `\\`` in your code: `'\\'`.

Comment: Just use string.find("1"); because \" is used to mark qoutes inside a string ant it's called escape sequence string. Just think of \" as just " inside a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    // build a test string and display it
    auto str = std::string(R"text("aaaaaaaa"\1\"bbbbbbbbb")text");
    std::cout << "input : " << str << std::endl;

    // build the regex to extract two quoted strings separated by "\1\"

    std::regex re(R"regex("(.*?)"\\1\\"(.*?)")regex");
    std::smatch match;

    // perform the match
    if (std::regex_match(str, match, re))
    {
        // print captured groups on success
        std::cout << "matched : " << match[1] << " and " << match[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

expected results:

```
input : "aaaaaaaa"\1\"bbbbbbbbb"
matched : aaaaaaaa and bbbbbbbbb
```